# modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations?

Tags: java

I can figure out why do I keep getting this error " modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations?" Do I need to make the main class static?

```
public class Main {
    abstract class Animal {
        abstract String Talk();
    }
    class Pet extends Animal {
        String Talk() {
            return "uh?";
        }
    }
    class Cat extends Pet {
        String Talk() {
            return "meow!";
        }
        String purr() {
            return "))";
        }
        class Dog extends Pet {
            String Talk() {
                return "woof";
            }
            String Bark() {
                return "@";
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pet[] pets = new Pet[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your classes outside of `Main` body.

Comment: Where are you trying to add `static`?

Comment: Move main(...) method to Main class

Comment: and `Dog` is an inner-class of `Cat`? You should really work on formatting code correctly (avoids this and other errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your brackets are wrong. Add one at the end of your Cat class and remove the last one